# Azure Active Directory Company Branding Not Showing on Sign-in Page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, branding

We are unable to get working our Azure Active Directory Company Branding. Neither the logo comes up nor the background image.

Checked on multiple devices with multiple time changing it on Azure.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz83e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Once You probably try to sign in with a Microsoft Account instead of Azure AD account. 
Then sign in with Azure Active Directory account you will continue see your company branded page.

Comment: Just tried that, didn't do anything. Still getting the same thing.

Comment: can you try to login in to [Microsoft](https://www.office.com/) incognito browser and see whether you can see brand logo there

Comment: Yeah, i have tried that too. Same behavior. Its even stays exactly same even when trying from mobile.

Comment: I have tried to repo the issue. When i initially update the custom image as per the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding) when i tried to login in to portal first time i faced the same issue, then i went to Microsoft login page and logged in there i can see the updated image. Again i verified in the azure portal the updated image was showing up.

Comment: Its still not getting resolved for me. If I remove the logo and background image, it loads default MS logo and background with out any problem. But not a customer logo or background.

Comment: I also saw that same problem with my App Registrations Branding Logo. Image was uploaded but now a cross mark in portal.

Comment: Can you provide me the detail process which you are following to upload the image so that i can help you further

Comment: Any updates on this? We have the same problem, logo is not displayed in user flow even if we uploaded it via Branding setup